# Minesweeper(simple) in c#

Tags: c#

so I'm working on some small thing and I'm kind of lost. This is what I have so far.

```
static void izris()
{
   Random bombe = new Random();
   int[,] polje = new int[7, 7];
   string stolpci = " ABCDEFG";
   int vrstice=1;
   foreach (char c in stolpci)
   {
       Console.Write(c);
       Console.Write(" ");

   }
   Console.WriteLine();
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            polje[i, j] = bombe.Next(0, 2);
        }
    }
    //izris polja
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        Console.Write(vrstice);
        vrstice++;
        Console.Write(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(polje[i,j]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

So what this does is, it prints a field of 7x7 that contains random numbers from 0 to 1. Now 1 means it is a mine, and 0 means it's not a mine. Now if you look, there are characters marking the columns(ABCDEFG) and numbers from 1-7 marking the rows. Now what I want to do is, for example the user would enter a string and the string would be B4. Then the program would check that and see if the field that the user selected is a mine(0) or a bomb(1). If it is a bomb it would also say how many bombs(1's) are nearby. I have no idea how to do this.
I was thinking of transforming the A-F characters into 0,6 numbers so I could index easier, but I don't know.

So I made this to check if the input is correct.

```
static void vnospolja()
    {
        string lokacija;
        string nekaj = "A";
        int nekaj2 = nekaj[0] - 'A';
        lokacija = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        while (lokacija.Length < 2)
        {
            string pravilnalokacija=lokacija.Substring(0,1);
            int pravilnalokacijaint = pravilnalokacija[0];
            if(pravilnalokacijaint>65 && pravilnalokacijaint<72)
            {
                Console.Write("input ok");
            }

            string drugiznak = lokacija.Substring(1, 1);
            int drugiznakint = drugiznak[0];
            if(drugiznakint>0 && drugiznakint<8)
            {
                Console.Write("input ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I need some ideas on how I would do this, for instance user enters A4, so the input is correct. So how do I actually move accros my 7,7 field and check for A4? I don't understand this, my friend told me something about a second indexer in my multidimensional field but I have no clue.

Comment: Okay, so you wrote the code to create the minefield, populate it with mines, and print the result on the screen. The next thing you'll want to be able to do is read in input from the user (`Console.ReadLine`). You'll probably need a function to find the neighbors of the selected cell, and you'll need to remember which cells have been uncovered. We won't write that code for you, but give it shot and if you run into any *specific* problems, then come back here and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: Your index idea will work, definitely map a letter to an index. This will make your look up easier. As for searching for near by bombs, you will need to scan the array for adjacent cells. Best approach is to start from the selected cell and start to scan in every direction. You can use OOP to solve this by creating nodes (graph-like solution). If each node knows its adjacent nodes then it is very easy to recursively find all adjacent bombs.

Answer (score 1):

to just convert the users input into 0 based coordinates you could use this.

```
static int[] GetInput()
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    //validate input here..
    int x = input[0] - 'A'; //converts char to int
    int y = int.Parse(input.Substring(1)) - 1;
    return new int[]{ x, y };
}
```

You could use this method by doing...

```
var selected = GetInput();
if(polje[selected[0]][selected[1]] == 1)
{
    //its a bomb
}
```

Comment: But would this work with my field?

Comment: yes. I will show how to call.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Dictionary instead of using an Array?

```
            Dictionary<string, bool> p = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            if (p.ContainsKey("a1"))
            {
                //do something
            }
            else { } // not a bomb/mine
```

So you can easily check wether the field is a bomb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate a user input, such as `B4` into row and column, here is a simple way you could do it.  Since you already have a collection of column names `stolpci`, you can use [`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx), which will find the position of a character in a string.  For example, `B` is found in place 2 (using 0-based indexing)

```
 01234567
" ABCDEFG"
```

Since you would want `B` to map to column number 1, rather than 2 in the minesweeper array, you would need to subtract one.

As far as the number part goes, you can use [`int.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the number.  Once again, the number is going to be off by one, because row number 4 actually corresponds to row number 3 in the 0-based indexing for the minesweeper array.  So your final result might look something like this:

```
var input = "B4";  // this would come from the user, hard-coding for example
var column = stolpci.IndexOf(entry.Substring(0, 1));   // 2
var row = int.Parse(entry.Substring(1, 1));  // 4
var isBomb = polje[row - 1, col - 1] == 1;  // offset by 1 for 0-based indexing
// do something with this
```